# Copying files from ubuntu linux to windows xp

Tags: linux, windows

I am a user and i am accessing linux through putty and i wrote somany programs in unix using putty and gedit but now i need to copy all files into windows.

how to copy directory(linux) to folder(windows) without installing any softwares?
If it is necessary to install software to copy files then please tell me the process of using that software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use PuTTY, install [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/download.php), and point it to the same server.

Answer (score 1):

There are a million ways to do this. The most "windows" way would be to install samba, then mount your windows share, and then copy your files to the mount point.

Google is more than capable of telling you how to do each of these tasks for your particular distro. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The following software should help you ( I am assuming that you need to copy from Windows )

http://ext2read.blogspot.com/2010/04/ext2read-22-released-now-with-lvm2-and.html

Ext2Read - You can copy folders, files from an ext2/3/4 partition drive. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I personally like to use netcat (nc) to move files between machines, since the "server" (the machine not initiating the transfer) is single-use and also created from the command line, not something that gets left running and might be abused later.

Approximately speaking, on the sending machine:

tar -czf some_directory | nc -l -p some_number_above_1024 -q 1

on the receiving machine

nc ip_addr_of_sender same_number_above_1024 | tar -xzv

The downside is that you need nc (a tiny c program) on the windows box, and it's useful to have tar, though you can also just save the file and open it with winzip.

Alternatively, there's an answer floating around here on how to use nc to make a single-use web server, so you can use the window's machine's web browser to grab the file.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a portable FTP server (e.g. this one: http://www.pablosoftwaresolutions.com/html/quick__n_easy_ftp_server_lite.html) to run on Windows, so no need to install software. Just run the server, copy your files using the `ftp` command on your Linux box, and stop the server.